# fields/column logical names of webpage to be checked

Tags: robotframework

How can I get the fields logical names of webpage to be tested so that I can write script in Robot Framework.I understand we use key words to check/validate the controls (input, out and images etc) as required. I am come from manual testing background so obviously need to know how does it all work in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has developer tools which you can use to inspect the page. For example, on chrome and firefox you can press <kbd>Control-Shift-I</kbd> to open the developer tools window. On IE I think it's <kbd>F12</kbd>. From there you can inspect the elements that make up the page.

You can also simply ask the members of your development team to help you.